# How can i create a regex with String contains $

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to ask about a regex pattern, 
the example of the string is : "This is So Good $AAAA" or it can be "This is so Good $AAAA & $BBBB"

in that example, i want to retrieve and change the $AAAA and $BBBB to an link,
and the link format is http://www.webname.com/name.aspx?name=AAAA or name=BBBB

thanks.

Comment: use \ to escape special characters such as ^,+,-, ...

Answer (score 1):

Regex for matching that should be `\$\w{4}` if you want to match only $ and 4 letters. Or  `\$\w+` if it is unknown number of letters more than 1.

Comment: here is what i've tried
@"\[$]([a-z|A-Z]{4})(-[a-z|A-Z]{1})*"

but it can't be a link,

Comment: It can't be link? You don't neeed link here. When you match strings in text just replace it with http://www.webname.com/name.aspx?name=MATCH.

Comment: here is my example, can you please help me sir ?
for (int a = 0; a < objComment.message.Length; a++)
{
Match match = Regex.Match(objComment.message, @"[$]([a-z|A-Z]{4})(-[a-z|A-Z]{1})*");
if (match.Success)
{string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
temp1 = string.Format("<a href=\"http://www.tradergods.com/stock/stockdetail.aspx?stock={0}\">{1}</a>", key.ToUpper(),key);}} string output = Regex.Replace(objComment.message, @"\[$]([a-z|A-Z]{4})(-[a-z|A-Z]{1})*", string.Format(temp1));